# Confusion with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. WHERE clause introduces a condition on individual rows; HAVING clause introduces a condition on aggregations
2. Aggregate functions can be used in both the SELECT and HAVING clauses
3. Aggregate function cannot be used on right hand side of equation after having  i.e  having salary=avg(salary)

Question-> Am I right on all three points particularly  the third one i wonder if there are any cases where the third one is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes, but you must use an aggregate with HAVING, it is optional with a regular SELECT statement.
3. Yes, it wouldn't make sense to interrogate "salary" without an aggregate function, as using the HAVING clause indicates you have already aggregated above the individual row level.